# Keycloak stock LDAP Federation and Dynamic Roles Loaded from External Database via JTA Entities

Tags: keycloak

I'm using Keycloak version 20.0.2 with stock LDAP Federation Provider, unsynced. I need for roles to be loaded from an external database but not necessarily synced with Keycloak, roles can be synced with Keycloak but preferably I would like for the roles to be looked up from external  database at login and when I view the user from admin console but roles not defined in keycloak.

I don't want roles synced when LDAP users are loaded from LDAP, I need for the roles to be dynamically looked up from the database.

I have tried to use [AbstractLDAPStorageMapper](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/cc9326fcad3aa209adba8f1c16daae8f2699a702/federation/ldap/src/main/java/org/keycloak/storage/ldap/mappers/AbstractLDAPStorageMapper.java) with JTA datasource and I am able to retrieve a list of roles in a List format when I view my user in admin console but the roles aren't defined.

```
@Override
public Stream<RoleModel> getRoleMappingsStream() {
     System.out.println("]--> getRoleMappingsStream");
     Stream<RoleModel> roleMappings = super.getRoleMappingsStream();
 
     String email = delegate.getEmail();
     List<String> rolesDB = getRolesFromDB(email);
     for (String roleDB : rolesDB){
         System.out.println("]--> " + roleDB);
         RoleModel roleModel = realm.getRole(roleDB);
         if (roleModel == null){
             roleModel = realm.addRole(roleDB);
             logger.debugf("Adding role [%s] ", roleDB);
             System.out.println("[--> Adding role " + roleDB);
         }
         logger.debugf(
           "Granting role [%s] to user [%s] during user import from LDAP", 
           roleDB, 
           email
         );
         System.out.println("Granting role " + roleDB + " to user " + email + " during user import from LDAP");
         delegate.grantRole(roleModel);
         roleMappings = Stream.concat(roleMappings, Stream.of(roleModel));
     }

     RoleModel role = getRole(realm);
     if (role != null) {
         roleMappings = Stream.concat(roleMappings, Stream.of(role));
     }
     return roleMappings;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my code worked, my function getRolesFromDB wasn't returning any values. After fixing the function the code started working.